# Оптимальный вариант конкатенации строк TextBox.Lines

Tags: c#, winforms

Результатом выполнения кода должна быть строка:

```
'Категор 1', 'Категор 2', 'Категор 3'
```

Значения *"Категор n"* вводятся в `TextBox` (см. скриншот).
Количество строк с *"Категор n"* не более 10-ти.

Сделал следующий код для реализации данной задачи:

```
string crit_2;            
int s; // счётчик
int c; // кол. строк
crit_2 = "";
s = 0;
c = textBox7.Lines.Count();
foreach (string str in textBox7.Lines)
{
    s++;
    if (s == 0) // первая строка
    {
        crit_2 = crit_2 + "'" + str + "'";
    }
    if (s > 0) // промежуточные строки
    {
        crit_2 = crit_2 + "'" + str + "', ";
    }
    if (s == c) // последняя строка
    {
        crit_2 = crit_2 + "'" + str + "'";
    }
}
richTextBox1.AppendText(crit_2 + "\r\n");
```

**Вопрос**
Будет ли оптимальным и грамотным данный код для решения данной задачи?
Или есть способы лучше?

**Скриншот**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант чуть покороче, без использования `Select`-a, но, возможно, менее интуитивно понятный:

```
string crit_2 = "'" + string.Join("', '", textBox7.Lines) + "'";
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Добавляем через LINQ кавычки.
2. Сцепляем строки через запятую.

   `string.Join(", ", textBox7.Lines.Select(x => string.Format("'{0}'", x)))`

http://ideone.com/qQir7L